# Python scripting to download and read json response

Tags: python

I would like to write a python script to get the response from the URL and then pick one parameter from the response and save that value in output file.format of url output is JSON.
We will be running this script once in a day and will grab that value and later we may have to make a chart to see the increment in value.
Paramter is something like this :
"TotalVolumeConsumedInBytes": 0

I am new to python so any help to start with will be good.
Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ - i think the first page almost gives you everythink to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is just an example url, but it works on python3:

```
import requests

req = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Miguel-Frazao/world-data/master/countries_data_assoc.json').json()
TotalVolumeConsumedInBytes = req['AD']['name'] # Andorra

# write to file:
with open('data.txt', 'a') as f: # adjust file path here, this case is on append mode, you you want to rewrite every time change the 'a' to 'w'
    f.write('TotalVolumeConsumedInBytes: {}'.format(TotalVolumeConsumedInBytes))
```

If you are using python2:

```
import urllib2
import json

req = urllib2.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Miguel-Frazao/world-data/master/countries_data_assoc.json')
req = json.load(req)
param = req['AD']['name'] # Andorra

# write to file:
with open('tests.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(param)
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way is to use the `urllib3`. [Here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#json-content) you can find the step-by-step  usage example that do very similar thing to what you described with getting JSON data.